# SQL Server query logic

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can we write a nice query for below requirements.

I have `employee`table where it has 3 columns

```
1. Employee ID
2. ManagerID
3. LocationID
```

I would like to return output which returns first (1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or none). Here are the additional conditions.

```
1. EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID = 2222 and LocationID = 3333
2. EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID is null and LocationID = 3333
3. EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID = 2222 and LocationID = 3333
4. EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID is null and LocationID is null
```

I would like to have logic like this. Can you anyone help me to get query.

Comment: can you be more clear in your question. First tell us what are the conditions and what's the output you need

Comment: Sorry, but I can't for the life of me figure out what you're asking.

Comment: What is the difference between condition 1 and condition 3?

Comment: Since it's impossible to fully understand your requirements, please provide **sample data** and the **expected result** `A.S.A.P.`

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest you need to clarify what it is that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help to share your thoughts.

Here is the one solution which i used.

```
Select * from (
Select * from Employee where EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID = 2222 and LocationID = 3333;
Union 
Select * from Employee where EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID is null and LocationID = 3333
Union
Select * from Employee where  EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID = 2222 and LocationID = 3333
Union
Select * from Employee where  EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID is null and LocationID is null
) z where z.rownum = 1
```

This worked well for my scenario.Please post me if you find any good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
SELECT * FROM employee
WHERE EmployeeID = 1233 
AND (ManagerID = 2222 OR ManagerID IS NULL)
AND (locationID = 3333 OR locationID IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember the Operator Precedence in Sql Server, Sql Server checks/filters results in the Order of NOT-->And-->OR , It can get a bit confusing when you have many conditions to check against, so it is better to use Parenthesis to Break Conditions into smaller pieces and which is more Readable and easier to maintain and debug.

```
SELECT EmployeeID, ManagerID, LocationID
FROM employee
WHERE EmployeeID  = 1233 
AND (ManagerID = 2222 OR ManagerID IS NULL) 
AND (LocationID = 3333 OR LocationID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for all sharing your thought.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this,can`t tell from your question

```
SELECT  * FROM employee
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID = 2222 and LocationID = 3333 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID is null and LocationID = 3333 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID = 2222 and LocationID = 3333 THEN 2 ELSE 3 END,
EmployeeID = 1233 and ManagerID is null and LocationID is null THEN 3 ELSE 4 END
```